# Lambda function captures wrong "this" pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, shared-ptr

I'm having a problem with making one trivial C++ project involving lambda-expressions and shared pointers to work. The project is in Visual Studio, Debug, x64. This is the code I have.

Class1.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <functional>

class Class1
{
    int m_data;
    const int* m_data_ptr;
public:
    std::function<int(int)> m_func;
    Class1(int, int);
    void Assign(const int&);
};
```

Class2.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Class1.h"

class Class2
{
    Class1 m_class1obj;
public:
    Class2(int, int);
    void Assign(const int&);
    int Compute(int);
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Class1.h"
#include "Class2.h"

Class1::Class1(int i, int j) : m_data(j), m_data_ptr(nullptr)
{
    m_func = [i, this](int x)
    {
        int val = *m_data_ptr;
        return (val + m_data + i)*x;
    };
    std::cout << "Creating class1 object!\n";
}
void Class1::Assign(const int& v)
{
    m_data_ptr = &v;
}
Class2::Class2(int i, int j) : m_class1obj(i, j)
{
    std::cout << "Creating class2 object!\n";
}
void Class2::Assign(const int& v)
{
    m_class1obj.Assign(v);
}
int Class2::Compute(int v)
{
    return m_class1obj.m_func(v);
}
int main()
{
    int val = 4;
    /*
    Class2 class2obj(3, 5);
    class2obj.Assign(val);
    std::cout << class2obj.Compute(23.0) << std::endl;
    */
    std::shared_ptr<Class2> class2_ptr;
    class2_ptr = std::make_shared<Class2>(Class2(3, 5));
    class2_ptr->Assign(val);
    std::cout << class2_ptr->Compute(23) << std::endl;
}
```

The code compiles fine, but crashes while executing the last line of `main()`. While debugging, I found that the problem discovers itself upon completion of the line `class2_ptr = std::make_shared<Class2>(Class2(3, 5));` For some reason, when lambda in line `m_func = ...` captures the `this` pointer at `Class1` object's construction time, it records the address that becomes different from the object's address right after the smart pointer for `Class2` has been created! It seems the first recorded address becomes outdated. When I call `class2_ptr->Compute(23)`, I end up dereferencing a null pointer at `int val = *m_data_ptr;`, thus causing the crash, even though I assigned a non-null address in `class2_ptr->Assign(val);` prior to calling `m_func`! But why did the address of `this` change? It is because of internal reallocation of the object in memory hidden from a user? If so, why didn't the compiler reassign the proper value of `this` in the storage of `m_func`? Also, despite having the wrong address of the object of `Class1` recored in `m_func`, the other data member `m_data` is accessed with correct value in `m_func`.

**An important thing** is that if I comment out the last four lines in main() and remove comments for the other three lines, the program does not crash! Clearly, using shared pointer has something to do with it. 
Is there a problem in improper use of lambda expressions or smart pointers in this case? I can't seem to find the explanation in the C++ standard for my situation.

Thanks for all the comments explaining what's going on!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::make_shared<Class2>(Class2(3, 5))` creates a temporary `Class2`, which is moved into `shared_ptr` storage, and then the original is destroyed.

Your lambda captures an address of that temporary, and uses it after the temporary is destroyed.

You need to avoid creating the temporary and construct `Class2` directly in `shared_ptr` storage: `std::make_shared<Class2>(3, 5);` .

Or even better, get rid of the lambda. I'm not sure why you want to use it there.

Comment: Amazing. All because of that boiler plate with shared pointer construction that I copy-pasted from other pieces of code without giving it a second thought! Indeed, just doing `class2_ptr = std::make_shared<Class2>(3, 5);` is the right way!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: However, why could I witness that the value of `m_data` was recored correctly? If lambda accesses the data member of `Class1` only through the invalid pointer `this` it captured, does it mean that those are just remnants of the destroyed object?

Comment: @MajinSaha Yes, I think you just got lucky with `m_data`.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler did what you told it to.

> If so, why didn't the compiler reassign the proper value of this in the storage of m_func?

because you never told it to?

```
[i, this](int x)
{
    int val = *m_data_ptr;
    return (val + m_data + i)*x;
};
```

the value of `this` is captured the moment you create the lambda.

No magic, other than dereferencing it when you use a member variable, happens.

Then you copy `m_func` from one object to another; the pointer in the lambda still points at the old object.  Then the old object is destroyed.  Then you call `m_func`.

Your copy constructor is broken.  Delete it:

```
  class Class1 {
    Class1(Class1 const&)=delete;
```

because you store a pointer-to-yourself in the guts of `m_func` and you never fix it while copying.

This results in your code not compiling; a fix makes it compile and removes the bug as well:

```
 class2_ptr = std::make_shared<Class2>(3, 5);
```

the original created a temporary `Class2`, then copied it into the shared ptr; this version creates one directly in place.

Another approach is to fix the broken `m_func`:

```
std::function<int(Class1*, int)> m_func;
```

and

```
m_func =  [i](Class1* self, int x)
{
    int val = *self->m_data_ptr;
    return (val + self->m_data + i)*x;
};
```

And where you use it:

```
return m_class1obj.m_func(&m_class1obj, v);
```

and now you no longer have to `=delete` `Class1`'s copy ctor, nor change how you construct it.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I was using the second option by passing `Class1*` to `m_func` to avoid the crash, although I couldn't explain the bevavior of the crashing code up until now.